# Eclipse EGit: Transport Error with Bitbucket

Tags: eclipse, bitbucket, egit

[image]

This is the error I get.

I reinstalled everything and I am still getting the same error.
This is my HTTPS address: https://karlmorrison@bitbucket.org/Drotth/medialibrary.git

What is the problem behind this, then I might be able to search on!